# How do I automatically store Date in JPA entity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a JPA entity in Spring where I have a created_at field of type `Date`. I want to automatically initialize it to current date. How can I achieve this? Here's my code:

```
public class ClientModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private BigInteger id;
    private String client_id;
    private String client_name;
    private String client_secret;
    private String status;
    private Date created_at;
}
```

Currently I am doing this,

```
java.util.Date javaDate = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(javaDate.getTime());
client.setCreated_at(sqlDate);
```

Is there any alternative to this?

Comment: You may want to use the java.time API instead of java.util.Date/java.sql.Date if this is possible for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CreatedDate` annotation as shown in below example:

```
public class ClientModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private BigInteger id;
    private String client_id;
    private String client_name;
    private String client_secret;
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date created_at;
}
```

While creating new `ClientModel`, do not set any value for `created_at`. Spring will automatically initialize it to current date.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise in a more JPA-friendly way via events.

Example
`@PrePersist  void onPrePersist() {created_at = new java.util.Date();}`

This way entity will not be bind with Spring. So if the same entity needed in Non Spring environment then also it will work.